# How do you rename multiple dataframes by their column names in R?

Tags: r

Newbie so apologies any mistakes in how I'm asking this, but I'm wondering how to rename my dataframes using the first column heading name and write csvs. This is going to sound like a weird thing to want to do but basically part of the unique ID for each dataframe have ended up in the column headings.

I am able to rename the dataframes with the desired names using:

```
write.csv(DF1, file = paste0(colnames(DF1)[1], ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
```

What I'd like to do is to do this for all dataframes in a list "L". (Perhaps with a loop?)

Ideally I'd like to do this with everything in the column heading up to the first "_".

Comment: Try `lapply(L, function(i)write.csv(i, file = paste0(colnames(i)[1], ".csv"), row.names = FALSE))`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm getting NULLs e.g. "$`217`NULL"

Comment: I just followed the code you did for 1 of them. I can't know what went wrong...

Comment: My mistake, that's worked actually. Thanks!